# Is there official guidance for beginning the name of a boolean property with 'Is'? (e.g., 'IsDeleted')

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, naming-conventions

I like using the boolean property naming convention `Is______`, such as `IsDeleted`, `IsDefault`, etc. But I am being challenged on this. So is there any "official" guidance on the subject?  I haven't been able to find any.

(And, yes, I know this is minutiae.)

Comment: What is the other naming convention that you are being challenged with?

Comment: To these who attempt to close this: it is not opinion-based - there is a specific prescription regarding it in the naming guidelines.

Comment: The alternative would be to not use the 'Is' part and just use "Deleted" For example, almost every entity we have has a deleted flag of IsDeleted, which to me is slightly easier to understand than just "Deleted".

Comment: @Greg Only seems to work with verbs. If the boolean is supposed to reference a noun such as `Node`, `IsNode` describes it perfectly while `Node` would leave me confused. Should I even mention `Noded`?

Comment: Along with @Jim's comment, `if (object.IsDeleted)` reads better than `if (object.Deleted)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) on MSDN:

> √ DO name Boolean properties with an affirmative phrase (CanSeek
>   instead of CantSeek). Optionally, you can also prefix Boolean
>   properties with "Is," "Can," or "Has," but only where it adds value.

So basically guidelines do encourage usage of `Is`, `Has`, `Can` etc. As an example, the case with deleted entities in your application, which are marked with `IsDeleted` flag. "slightly easier to understand" is value enough to keep this `Is` part.

Personally I also follow this guideline because it turns some parts of code into completely valid sentences, which improves readability. Consider:

```
if (object.IsDeleted)
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO, but I do see the argument being made that "Is, can and Has does NOT add value here".

Comment: @Rob, absolutely not, at least is was not my intention. Let me elaborate in edit.

Comment: Is, Can, and Has, simply put, makes it easier to read and understand the code.

Comment: I completely agree that Is, Can and Has should always be used because it makes it easier to read and instantly shows the developer that it's a boolean. My comment was stating that the OP is looking for ammo against the people challenging him, and they will most likely use the argument that they don't add value.

Comment: @Rob, I really like the point you make about "it instantly shows the developer it is a Boolean."  I think that is where the 'Is' does add value.

Comment: There is also the scenario of multi-values - let's say there was three values possible, NotDeleted, Deleted, and DeleteIn30Days. Then a property name of "DeleteStatus" would be in order and could be based on an enum.  The point being, using 'Is_' tells you it's a Boolean, not something else. Whereas a 'Deleted' field could be bool or multi-value.

Comment: "it instantly shows the developer it is a Boolean." is one tretcherous step before hungarian notation.